# On usage of DbContext in ASP.NET using EF 6.1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

Since I have been working on my web application with MVC framework, I have been wondering about where I should have a definition of `DbContext`. I am aware of memory leak and normally, that is in `ConsoleApplication`, I would enclosed usage of `DbContext` withing `using() {}` clause. However, Web Application seems to be different and I am pretty sure lifetime of `DbContext` is different and I cannot just dispose it a controller and then try to read from it in Views. Or maybe I am wrong here. At first, I was creating multiple references in each Action. I came with this idea to put `DbContext` definition as a `readonly private` field within each controller:

```
public HomeController : controller
{
    private readonly MyDBContext myDbContext = new MyDBContext();

    // ... and in actions

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // ... usage of myDbContext
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        // ... usage of myDbContext
    }

    public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        // ... usage of myDbContext
    }

    public ActionResult Delete()
    {
        // ... usage of myDbContext
    }
}
```

Do you think it is correct.

Cheers!

---

EDIT:
I changed the code to this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IQueryable<MyViewModel> viewModel = null;
    using (MyDBContext dB = new MyDBContext())
    {
        viewModel = from st in dB.Students
                    join d in dB.Departments on st.DepartmentID equals d.DepartmentID
                    join g in dB.Genders on st.GenderID equals g.GenderID
                    select new MyViewModel
                    {
                        StudentID= st.StudentID,
                        StudentName = st.StudentName,
                        Gender = g.GenderName,
                        DepartName = d.DepartmentName
                    };
    }
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

and exception was thrown saying: "***The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed***" when I refer to `@Model` in View in the line:

```
@foreach (MyViewModel item in @Model) // compiler points at @Model
```

PLEASE Note that the code works otherwise, without any other changes but removing `using() {}`.

Comment: You can check this article: http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2013/03/27/managing-entity-framework-dbcontext-lifetime-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Comment: both techniques are the same in the MVC application since the context will not stay alive after you return the result from the action to the view

Comment: Your concept of awhat a model is are not MVC. The Model should not contain anything mot materialized. Your select viewmodel should not never ever be a delayed query, all processing should be finished when the method is ended.

Comment: Why is it delayed then? How can I sort it out? Is this something I can control? I do my best based on my knowledge!

Comment: use ToList function and Include if you are trying to access navigation properties in your View

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @HadiHassan, currently I convert `IQueryable<>` to list and it stopped throwing the exception. Thanks mate :). Do I need to add `Include`? I don't know how to use `Include` in LINQ method syntax. I have a problem with `Join()`. It's quite tricky :/

Comment: I've just read about deferred and immediate query operators. This link on [Classification of Standard Query Operators by Manner of Execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882641.aspx) has been very useful :)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is different. The Controller is dead when the view is called. Use using within the actions in the controller, so not keep a DbContext around.

Generally: NOTHING is different in MVC than in any other .NET technology, in regards of the handling of and EF context.

Comment: OK. Now I am confused. I followed your suggestion and enclosed `DbContext` in `using() {}` in a controller and returned ViewModel to `View()` and I've got this exception: "The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed." I am going to EDIT the question to show the code that causes exception!

Comment: If your view is having access to the DbContext something is seriously wrong with your understanding of MVC. A Model should ONLY  contain data, the view should not do any database operations at all with the model. You violate best practices and put processing into the view. This is NOT MVC.

Comment: The fact that programm worked different way that I expected does not have to mean I have a wrong understanding of MVC. The code was wrong because I wasn't aware of certain things. And now I am and have changed the code! You are criticising me here quite significantly. I don't know for what, that I came here to learn more? You have to underastand that I am in a stage of learnign mechanics not only behind MVC but ASP.NET itself!!

Answer (score 0):

Try a ToList as in select new {...}.ToList()
You are trying to access a data from a querable source. That source is closed on the end of the using scope.

Answer (score 0):

Since `viewModel` is an `IQueryable<MyViewModel>`, it doesn't hold the data in the controller. It contains an execution plan of your query which will be executed when you do this in your view

```
@foreach (MyViewModel item in @Model)
```

You got the error because the above syntax is outside of the `using` block so the `DbContext` is already disposed and the query can't be executed at that moment. Although removing the `using` block would make the code works without any errors, it's not the best practice for MVC. The model is supposed to only hold the data and the view isn't supposed to do any database operations at all.

The correct way for your case is using `IEnumerable<MyViewModel>` instead of `IQueryable<MyViewModel>` as the model, so `viewModel` will hold the data after the `using` block. You can use [ToList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method to force the execution of the query inside the `using` block as below

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<MyViewModel> viewModel = null;
    using (MyDBContext dB = new MyDBContext())
    {
        viewModel = (from st in dB.Students
                    join d in dB.Departments on st.DepartmentID equals d.DepartmentID
                    join g in dB.Genders on st.GenderID equals g.GenderID
                    select new MyViewModel
                    {
                        StudentID= st.StudentID,
                        StudentName = st.StudentName,
                        Gender = g.GenderName,
                        DepartName = d.DepartmentName
                    }).ToList();
    }
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

and make sure you have the below syntax at the top of your view code

```
@model IEnumerable<MyViewModel>
```